# ¿Cómo poner las últimas entradas de un blog en django?

Tags: python, django

quiero imprimir las últimas entradas de un blog en django pero no sé dónde está el fallo porque no se imprime en la web. Puede que sea alguna tontería pero no la localizo.

Tengo un modelo que se llama *Article*.

Esta es la vista:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
    from django.core.paginator import Paginator
    from blog.models import Category, Article
    from django.utils import timezone
```

Esta es la función *ultimos_posts* para que se filtre por fecha descendiente y aparezcan solo 3 entradas del blog. En esta función *Article* es el modelo que estoy utilizando para sacar los datos:

```
    def ultimos_posts(request):
        # Obtener los tres últimos posts ordenados por fecha descendente
        ultimos_posts = Article.objects.all().order_by("-created_at")[:3]
    
        # Filtrar los posts que se hayan creado antes de la fecha actual
        ultimos_posts = ultimos_posts.filter(created_at__lte=timezone.now())
    
        # Renderizar la plantilla 'list.html' y pasarle el contexto
        context = {'ultimos_posts': ultimos_posts}
        return render(request, 'list.html', context)
```

Así lo imprimo en la template *list.html*:

```
    {% for post in ultimos_posts %}
                <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
                <p> {{ post.created_at}}</p>
                <p> {{ post.user.last_name }}</p>
          
    
    {% endfor %}
```

Esta es la url del blog:

```
    urlpatterns = [
        path('articulos/',views.list, name="list_articles"),
        path('categoria/<int:category_id>', views.category, name="category"),
        path('articulo/<int:article_id>', views.article, name="article"),
        path('ultimos_posts/',views.ultimos_posts, name="ultimos_posts"),
    
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

verifica si tu función ultimos_posts está correctamente vinculada en el archivo urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

Comment: El archivo urls.py de la aplicación principal está asi y no funciona, muchas gracias por responder

Comment: El blog funciona el crear nuevos posts, modificarlos etc.. a través del panel de administración, pero que se muestre las últimas entradas no funciona

Answer (score 0):

Una vez que hiciste un slice a un queryset no puedes realizar un filtro sobre el mismo, puesto que Django ya ejecuta una consulta a la base de datos en ese caso.

Creo que la solución sería realizar el filtro directamente, en lugar de primero obtener un slice de todos y luego filtrar, algo así:

```
ultimos_posts = Article.objects.filter(created_at__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-created_at')[:3]
```

Si deseas saber cuándo se ejecuta un Queryset, aquí encontré un artículo que lo indica: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/django-2-by/9781788472487/c0d84fbe-ed96-47e5-b185-cf86335da8d6.xhtml